# Spark Streaming Execution Flow

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am a newbie to Spark Streaming and I have some doubts regarding the same like

1. Do we need always more than one executor or with one we can do our job
2. I am pulling data from kafka using createDirectStream which is receiver less method and batch duration is one minute , so is my data is received for one batch and then processed during other batch duration or it is simultaneously processed
3. If it is processed simultaneously then how is it assured that my processing is finished in the batch duration
4. How to use the that web UI to monitor and debugging

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need always more than one executor or with one we can do our job

It depends :). If you have a very small volume of traffic coming in, it could very well be that one machine code suffice in terms of load. In terms of fault tolerance that might not be a very good idea, since a single executor could crash and make your entire stream fault.

> I am pulling data from kafka using createDirectStream which is
>   receiver less method and batch duration is one minute , so is my data
>   is received for one batch and then processed during other batch
>   duration or it is simultaneously processed

Your data is read once per minute, processed, and only upon the completion of the entire job will it continue to the next. As long as your batch processing time is less than one minute, there shouldn't be a problem. If processing takes more than a minute, you will start to accumulate delays.

> If it is processed simultaneously then how is it assured that my
>   processing is finished in the batch duration?

As long as you don't set `spark.streaming.concurrentJobs` to more than 1, a single streaming graph will be executed, one at a time.

> How to use the that web UI to monitor and debugging

This question is generally too broad for SO. I suggest starting with the Streaming tab that gets created once you submit your application, and start diving into each batch details and continuing from there.

Comment: spark.streaming.concurrentJobs is the count of jobs to be executed by single executor , so how your performance would be affected and is it recommended for it to be more than 1

Comment: Can you provide any resource to know about the web UI

Comment: @JSR29 concurrentJobs means that you can execute two jobs at a time (for example, if one of your jobs is stalling for more than a minute, the second one will still execute).

Comment: @JSR29 https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/08/new-visualizations-for-understanding-apache-spark-streaming-applications.html

Comment: For the answer of first part you said if traffic is low but our receiver doesn't what would be the traffic so it would continue to receive , then how can it process data

Comment: @JSR29 *"our receiver doesn't what would be the traffic"* If you don't have an estimate of the volume of your traffic, you really should. If not, start by having more resources than you think you should have, and slowly take them down as you see how much traffic you actually have. Getting the right cluster size isn't a rule of thumb, it's more of a trail and error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147188/discussion-between-jsr29-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Comment: But how will executor would know when to stop receiving and start processing data

Comment: @JSR29 You don't have to worry about that. You just define the execution graph, Spark will, once a minute, read as much as it can (according to all the settings you pass) from Kafka, and then stream these messages through the transformations you define.

Comment: "Once a minute" it means it doesn't read for whole batch duration? And then is some data is missed, if we have executors are more than one then would it receive for full batch duration.

Comment: The batch time means "how often should spark query kafka for information". It does not constantly keep an open connection.

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit more on monitoring

> How to use the that web UI to monitor and debugging

Monitor your application in the Streaming tab on localhost:4040, the main metrics to look for are **Processing Time** and **Scheduling Delay**. Have a look at the offical doc : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#monitoring-applications

> batch duration is one minute

Your batch duration a bit long, try to adjust it with lower values to improve your latency. 4 seconds can be a good start.

Also it's a good idea to monitor these metrics on Graphite and set alerts. Have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/29983398/3535853

Comment: How to compare between the resource usage while using the lower or higher batch duration